# Select from MySQL table without repetition

Tags: php, mysql, sql, select

I have three tables in my MySQL DB : schools, parents and students. students has two columns school_id and parent_id which links each row in students to a single row in parents and and a single row in schools. The structure is such that a parent may have children in a number of schools, yet there should be only one record for that parent. Now I want to select rows from parents such that only one row is pulled off no matter how many rows in students point to that parent. Currently my query looks like :

```
$stmt = $db->prepare( "SELECT p.* 
                       FROM parents p 
                          INNER JOIN studnts S ON p.id = s.parent_id 
                       WHERE s.school_id = :schoolID" );

$stmt->execute( array( ':schoolID'=> $schoolID ) );
```

I have even replaced `INNER JOIN` with `LEFT OUTER JOIN`. No change.

This query is pulling off a row from parents for every row in students. Any help?

Thanks.

Comment: Please show your database schema ?

Comment: @piet.t Thanks a lot. That solves the problem.

Comment: Note that the WHERE clause in your query checks a value in the LEFT OUTER JOINed table, hence would render it to be an INNER JOIN.

Comment: @Kickstart, are you saying that LEFT JOIN is equivalent to INNER JOIN when the former has a WHERE CLAUSE?

Comment: In this case yes. The difference is that an LEFT OUTER JOIN will return a row from parents where there is no matching row on studnts, in which case the columns from studnts would have the value of NULL. But your WHERE clause checks for a specific value in those columns hence will exclude any row where there is no matching row on studnts. Hence the results is the same as an INNER JOIN.

Comment: @Kickstart +1 and thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    SELECT 
            p.*
    FROM 
            parents p INNER JOIN studnts S ON p.id = s.parent_id 
    WHERE 
            s.school_id = :schoolID
    GROUP BY 
            p.parent_id

    or

    SELECT 
            DISTINCt p.parent_id, p.parent_name, p.parent_address ....etc
    FROM 
            parents p INNER JOIN studnts S ON p.id = s.parent_id 
    WHERE 
            s.school_id = :schoolID
```

to know more about GROUP BY

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-functions.html

to know more about DISTINCT

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/distinct-optimization.html

IF you want both student(s) name, along with parent
use GROUP_CONCAT

to know more about GROUP_CONCAT

https://www.percona.com/blog/2013/10/22/the-power-of-mysqls-group_concat/

Comment: `DISTINCT` is not a function (on a column), it's a part if `SELECT DISTINCT` and works on the whole selected rows. E.g. `SELECT DISTINCt(p.parent_id), p.parent_name` is the same as `SELECT DISTINCt p.parent_id, p.parent_name`, which is the same as `SELECT DISTINCt (p.parent_id, (p.parent_name)`. My tip is to skip those unnecessary parentheses, so that no one gets confused.

Comment: @jarlh ! True, Agreed !

Answer (score 2):

Simply using distinct in query will help

```
$stmt = $db->prepare( "SELECT distinct p.* 
                       FROM parents p 
                          INNER JOIN studnts S ON p.id = s.parent_id 
                       WHERE s.school_id = :schoolID" );

$stmt->execute( array( ':schoolID'=> $schoolID ) );
```